# Is there a way to hide the content overflow the canvas size?

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

I set a size for the canvas and used drawCircle. Since the circle is larger than the canvas, the circle will appear to be out of bounds.

```kotlin
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            MyApplicationTheme {
                // A surface container using the 'background' color from the theme
                Box(
                    contentAlignment = Alignment.Center,
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .fillMaxSize()
                        .background(Color.Black)
                ) {
                    Canvas(modifier = Modifier.size(300.dp).background(Color.Blue)){
                        drawCircle(
                            color = Color.White,
                            center = Offset(x = size.width / 2f, y = size.height / 2f),
                            radius = (size.minDimension / 2f)+50
                        )
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x5ScG.png)

I expect the part of overflow will hide，just like this：

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8uA6v.png)

what should I do？

Answer (score 0):

`Modifie.clipToBounds()` clips any drawing that is outside of Composable

```
/**

 * Clip the content to the bounds of a layer defined at this modifier.
 */
@Stable
fun Modifier.clipToBounds() = graphicsLayer(clip = true)
```

which is `Modifier.graphicsLayer{clip = true}` under the hood that you can use as

```
 Canvas(modifier = Modifier
                     .clipToBounds()
                    .size(300.dp).background(Color.Blue)){
                        drawCircle(
                            color = Color.White,
                            center = Offset(x = size.width / 2f, y = size.height / 2f),
                            radius = (size.minDimension / 2f)+50
                        )
                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this:

```
    // A surface container using the 'background' color from the theme
    Box(
        contentAlignment = Alignment.Center,
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .background(Color.Black)
    ) {
        Canvas(
            modifier = Modifier
                .size(300.dp)
                .background(Color.Blue)
        ){
            clipRect {
                drawCircle(
                    color = Color.White,
                    center = Offset(x = size.width / 2f, y = size.height / 2f),
                    radius = (size.minDimension / 2f)+50
                )
            }
        }
    }
```

[image]